# Print Folder Structure from ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a single Model named Folder. The model has a foreign key that points back to the primary key of the table. I use this structure to create a virtual folder tree.

My model looks like this:

```
class Folder
     has_many :folders
     belongs_to :folder, optional: true
end
```

After I create a few folders that are related to each other, I essentially create a tree with N branches. I cannot remember how this is supposed to be parsed so that I can print out the HTML in my view that will show the actual folder structure.

Essentially, my goal is to query for all folders that don't have a parent and work from there, like this.

```
@folders = Folder.all.where(folder_id: nil)
```

In my view

```
<ul>
    <% @folders.each do |i| %>
        <li>
            <%= i.name %>
             Somehow I need to grab the other child folders here and continue this process N times.
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a partial that looks at each item and either 1) renders the item as a regular li item (if the item is a file) or 2) recursively renders itself (if the item is a directory).

eg something like:

```
# index.html.erb (or whatever your endpoint is, if not index)
<%= render partial: "_entries.html.erb", locals: {entries: @folders} %>

# _entries.html.erb
<ul>
  <% entries.each do |item| %>
    <li>
      <% if item.is_directory? %>
        <!-- rerender this partial with files in current directory -->
        <%= render partial: "_entries.html.erb", locals: {entries: item.children} %>
      <% else %>
        <!-- render individual items -->
        <%= item.name %>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

The ul's should end up nested exactly as deep as they should be.

Comment: Also, not strictly related to your question, but check out https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree. Great lib for dealing with tree structures like this.

Comment: In fact, that lib gives you a method called `walk_tree` that seems to do exactly what you want, without having to implement this yourself.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!